# How to use different forms in single PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to create a single dynamic webpage with two separate forms:

1. Sign in form
2. Registration form.

This would mean one submit button for each form and clicking on one submit button should collect data from one form only. I tried the approach shown below but the data was not submitted to mySql database. I have tried running the forms individually and they do work with mysql database so I guess there should be something else wrong. The code below is stripped of details but I reckon the gist of it is inside. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{ 
doSomething(); 
} 
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Sign in"/>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{ 
doSomethngElse(); 
}
?>

<form id="form2" name="form2" action="" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Sign up"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You could just check if they the values are empty and if they are then skip over them and check the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I do like this:

Use 2 button with 1 name :

```
    //========== first form ==========
    <form name="form1" action....>

    fields

    <input type="submit" name="_Submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    // ========== second form ==========

    <form name="form2" action....>

    fields

    <input type="submit" name="_Submit" value="Sign up">
    </form>


    // ========== in php file do this  ==========

    <?php
    $submit = $_POST["_Submit"];

    if($submit=="Login"){

       // get login form data


    }else if($submit=="Sign up"){
       // get sign up form data
    }else{
      // submit is empty or undefined value
    }
    ?>
```

- I use this for more than 16 form in one page! this is very easy way to control forms buttons using if or switch!

Answer (score 1):

try first checking for post request

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
   echo "post occurs";              // only for testing to check whether post is occur or not

  if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
  { 
      doSomething(); 
  } 

  else if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
  { 
     doSomethngElse(); 
  }
  else
  {
        echo "no form is posted";
  }
 }
 else
 {
      echo "Post not happened";
  }
?>


<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Sign in"/>
</form>


<form id="form2" name="form2" action="" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Sign up"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, you can check if the values are empty so you could just do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2']) == ""){
     //The variable is empty
}
else
{
   //The variable is not empty

}
```

And if i correct you could just do

```
 if (!(empty($_POST['submit2'])){
         //This variable is not empty    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this answers your question directly, I think the rest of your code would be needed for that... but...

Why not just check a value in a single form element like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{ 
    if(!empty($_POST['submit1']) && $_POST['submit1']=='SignIn')
    {
        // Do Some Code... like:
        ?>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
        ...
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="SignIn"/>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['submit1']) && $_POST['submit1']=='SignUp')
    {
        // Do Some Other Code...
        ?>
        <form id="form2" name="form2" action="" method="post">
        ...
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="SignUp"/>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: This way is good but by the sounds of it he need's to learn more about multiple variable in a single php code